# Western Digital Hard Drive not showing the True Storage size after changing something with the Partioning in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, partitioning, data-recovery

I was trying to get back space from the hard drive since 32GB of it was free. This hard drive was used for my Macintosh Time-machine Backups.I have data stored on the non-viewable partition of this 500GB hard drive but I can only see and access 32GB of it in Window, Mac OS and Ubuntu. I wish to keep all of the data if I can. Other than spending crazy money on data recovery services or software, is there a way to reverse this process or allow the hidden data to be reclaimed? Your help greatly appropriated since I'm a true Numbie to Ubuntu! Model type: WDC WD5000AAKS-402AA0 (06.01D02)

Comment: '...after changing something with the Partioning in Ubuntu' - what did you do?

Comment: Good question, was playing around with Disks; found pre-installed on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I managed to remove the EFI Partition and the rest I can't recall. This drive was used in a Mac I had as an external backup. Looking for space to install a different OS, I decided to see if I could get some space from the remaining part of the untouched- Free Space of the hard drive.  It was late and I did what a child would do.. Something stupid!

Answer (score 0):

## TestDisk

Is powerful data recovery software, primarily designed to help recover lost partitions.

To install it:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

And run:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install testdisk hfsutils hfsplus hfsprogs
```

[**How to run**](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Running_TestDisk)

[**Step by Step**](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step)

Comment: Thanks for responding, I just tried this and I received the following message once I copied pasted the last part and pressed ENTER. Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package testdisk
E: Unable to locate package hfsprogs

Comment: FYI, I'm running Ubuntue 14.04 LTS via USB thumb drive, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Download from: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/testdisk/testdisk_6.14-2_i386.deb or http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/testdisk/testdisk_6.14-2_amd64.deb and http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/hfsprogs/hfsprogs_332.25-11_i386.deb or http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/hfsprogs/hfsprogs_332.25-11_amd64.deb